# How to get a value by key from inside a nested JSON Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Using the JSON result shown below. I'm trying to get the value from the "ActionId" which in this case is "b0160455-e9d5-4692-850e-4958c8c45f8c"

I need to access this value in a foreach loop when rendering to a Razor Page list view.

So far I've been able to access the first level objects:

Example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LogEvents.EventEntities)
{
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
}
```

But I just cant work out the required code to get the values from the nested array 'Properties' inside this JSON result:

```
  {
  "lastReadEventId": "event-58cc86503c8d08d8313d010000000000",
  "scannedEventCount": 1,
  "eventEntities": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-08-09T18:55:05.0779216+01:00",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "SourceContext",
          "value": "WebApp_RAZOR.Pages.Logs.IndexModel"
        },
        {
          "name": "ActionId",
          "value": "b0160455-e9d5-4692-850e-4958c8c45f8c"
        },
        {
          "name": "ActionName",
          "value": "/Logs/Index"
        },
        {
          "name": "RequestId",
          "value": "0HM1SHK90IVGB:00000001"
        },
        {
          "name": "RequestPath",
          "value": "/Logs/Index"
        },
        {
          "name": "SpanId",
          "value": "|e7eeae4d-4d24315c2124a72d."
        },
        {
          "name": "TraceId",
          "value": "e7eeae4d-4d24315c2124a72d"
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentId",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "MachineName",
          "value": "DESKTOP-OS52032"
        },
        {
          "name": "ProcessId",
          "value": 22676
        },
        {
          "name": "ThreadId",
          "value": 14
        }
      ],
      "messageTemplateTokens": [
        {
          "text": "superadmin@hjbuybub.onmicrosoft.com requested the Index page"
        }
      ],
      "eventType": "$DA057814",
      "level": "Information",
      "renderedMessage": "superadmin@gegerggere.onmicrosoft.com requested the Index page",
      "id": "event-5345465467567b575675",
      "links": {
        "Self": "api/events/event-55b5456yubu5u67ub7u5{?download,render,clef}",
        "Group": "api/events/resources"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Classes derived from json result:

```
    public class LogEvents
    {
        public string LastReadEventId { get; set; }
        public int ScannedEventCount { get; set; }
        public EventEntity[] EventEntities { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventEntity
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public Property[] Properties { get; set; }
        public MessageTemplateToken[] MessageTemplateTokens { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string RenderedMessage { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Links Links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public string Self { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Property
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessageTemplateToken
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried following other Q&A here, but everyone's requirements are always different and getting stuck.

Comment: Have you done a "paste json as classes" / used QuickType.io to generate classes from json?

Comment: I did paste the json result into classes using edit then paste special in Visual Studio. Just added them to my Q if this helps...

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to use Newtonsoft's Json.NET [json path](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) [implementation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var actionIds = JObject.Parse(json)
    .SelectTokens("$.eventEntities[*].properties[?(@.name == 'ActionId')].value")
    .Select(p => p.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Or with your class structure it should be:

```
var actionIds = Model.LogEvents
    .SelectMany(le => le.Properties)
    .Where(p => p.Name == "ActionId")
    .Select(p => p.Value) // also can add `ToString` here since Value is an object
    .ToList();
```

Comment: How would this work when iterating through a loop for Razor list view? i.e. the example I gave for the first level object was @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)

Comment: @OJB1 you are looking for something like [this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23007261/2501279)?

Comment: The json path implementation looks along the lines of what i'm after, not seen this before so reading up on it as we speak.

Comment: Cant figure it out... Using Newtonsoft's Json.NET json path implementation: I tried '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Properties[?(@.name == 'ActionId')].value])' but it wont even compile

Answer (score 1):

Try using CHOETL json reader([from nuggets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/)). What you need from there is load the JSON and read the JSON and use a dynamic "foreach item". If item.name == "ActionId", then do whatever you want with item.value.

Here's is the guide: https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LogEvents.EventEntities)
{
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level.Properties
        .Single(x => x.Name == "ActionId").Value)
}
```

It means "within the `item.Properties` array, get the only element x where `x.Name` equals `"ActionId"` and return its `.Value`

If you don't want it to crash when there is no such element, you could look at:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
  (
    item.Level.Properties
      .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ActionId") 
      ?? new Property(){ Value = "Not found" }
  ).Value
```

Single[OrDefault] insists on only one element matching the rule. If you don't want it to crash when there are multiple elements with a name of ActionId, use `[First/Last][OrDefault]`. If you want an ActionId that is neither first or last, you'll have to dig it out by whatever logic for finding them you demand (i.e. "the second one", "the one whose value starts with an 'a'" etc)

---

Really you shouldn't even be doing all this code in your view. The whole idea of preparing a model and sending it to the view is that the model is ready to go with simple properties and data, formatted and prepared for the view. You shouldn't be doing massively complicated amounts of LINQ, error handling, moel transformation etc in your view..

"Just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*" :)

Comment: Thanks Caius, I tried your above code and take on board your comments about not doing this level of query in the view. The doesn't compile for me anyway with "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propogating operator" message. Are you suggesting I should add the json returned data to a List in page model first before bringing it to the view?

Comment: I fixed the code up so it doesn't use a null prop, but yes; that's exactly what I'm saying. The model should have the data in it ready to go; it shouldn't be that your model contains this hugely complicated tree of objects that might/not be there/used, leaving your view to pick through them and act accordingly. The code that generates the model should do most of the flattening and verifying. That's not to say that a model shouldn't have elements that are hierarchical, it's just that the model should represent what the View needs to do its work, not a splurge of every irrelevant data item